# How to get text from ListView click and put it in another activity via intent

Tags: android, listview

At this moment app working not correctly. I want to click on item in Listview then app have to go in mainactivity and set text in TextView and picture to ImageView from resource.

Second Activity

```
    ListView lvMain = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvMain);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, names);

    lvMain.setAdapter(adapter);

    lvMain.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int 
     position, long id) {

            String name = ((TextView) view).getText().toString();

            Intent intent = new Intent(ListHeroes.this, MainActivity.class);

            intent.putExtra("name", name);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

Main Activity

```
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent 
   data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_CODE_PLAYER1:
                String name1 = data.getStringExtra("name");
                playerName1.setText(name1);
                break;
```

Answer (score 0):

On list view click do it like this:

```
 lvMain.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int 
 position, long id) {

        String name = names.get(position);

        Intent intent = new Intent(ListHeroes.this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("name", name);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

and then in the MainActivity get the name like this in your MainActivity's onCreate:

```
String name = String name = getIntent().getStringExtra("name");
```